# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x}}dx $

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I should find the result of $$\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x}}dx $$
So I have to study the convergence
In 0, i have $$\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x}=\frac{1-x-1+2x+\mathcal O(x^2)}{x}\stackrel{x\to0}\longrightarrow1$$,why can I say that if $$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x}}=1 $$so the integral is convergent in 0?Shouldn't I calculate the primitive firstly then I'll find the limit?
Thank you for replying

Comment: the result should be $\log(2)$

Comment: If you want to find the result, try [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show the function is continuous and bounded in a region close to zero to say that it converges as $x\to0$.  To be more precise, one could establish bounds:

$$0<\int_0^1\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x~\mathrm dx<\int_0^11~\mathrm dx=1$$

$$0<\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x~\mathrm dx<\int_1^\infty e^{-x}~\mathrm dx=\frac1e$$

So it converges and is bounded by

$$0<\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x~\mathrm dx<1+\frac1e$$

Specifically, we may use [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) to see the given integral is $\ln(2)$.

---

To solve the integral in an elementary fashion, consider the more general integral:

$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-(t+1)x}}x~\mathrm dx$$

Let $u=e^{-x}$ to get

$$I(t)=\int_0^1\frac{u^t-1}{\ln(u)}~\mathrm du$$

Now differentiate w.r.t. $t$ to get

$$I'(t)=\int_0^1u^t~\mathrm du=\frac1{t+1}$$

Integrate back to get

$$I(t)-I(0)=\int_0^t\frac1{x+1}~\mathrm dx=\ln(t+1)$$

Since it should be trivial that $I(0)=0$, we find that

$$I(1)=\ln(2)$$

As claimed.

Comment: How did you etablish the bounds?

Comment: For calculating the integral,the method i used is applying the definition.I separate the integral in 2;then the change of variables $$u=2x$$,and finally i use Chasles'relation to get $$ \int_{b}^{2b}{\frac{e^{-x}}{x}}dx;b\rightarrow 0$$,but how to get lnx with this method?

Comment: @mezzaluna Show that $\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x$ is decreasing, so $0<\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x$ for $0<x<1$.  For $x>1$, note that:$$0<\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x<e^{-x}-e^{-2x}<e^{-x}$$

Comment: I do not believe your approach will solve the integral so easily.  Instead, use $u=e^{-x}$ and differentiation under the integral.  I've edited the answer to include the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x
-\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-2x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x
-\int_{2\epsilon}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon}\frac{e^{-x}}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon}\frac{1+O(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}(\log(2)+O(\epsilon))\\[9pt]
&=\log(2)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing the integral as a double integral then interchanging limits:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x} dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{-2x}^{-x} e^y\frac{1}{x} dy dx$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{-\frac{y}{2}}^{-y} e^y \frac{1}{x} dx dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{y} \ln 2 dy$$

$$=\ln 2$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} - \expo{-2x} \over x}\,\dd x & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t\,\dd x =
\int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x\,\dd t =
\int_{1}^{2}{1 \over t}\,\dd t = \bbx{\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}